# How to add "Store app" project template to Visual basic?

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-api-code-pack

I wanted to build **windows phone app** using Visual basic. It requires **store app** project template which is not existing in my version!

I tried to download the *VS Express version 2013* and every time i start it shows Visual studio needs some repair. Even after the repair the same trouble shoots up again!! If possible render me the exact link for the visual studio version with which i would be able to build windows phone app.

Also is it possible to build windows 10 phone app in Windows 7?

Comment: You should fix the machine first in order to use VS2013.

Yes, you can build Windows 10 apps on Windows 7, but you will need a Windows 10 machine to execute them.

Comment: why don't you download vs2015 Community RC?  It can co-exist with vs2013 so that you don't have to deal with problems in vs2013.  btw, selecting tools for apache cordova during installation of vs2015 allows you to build cross-platform apps including Windows phone and Android and iphone, then you can use VB for Server side but you need to use JavaScript for client side.